# Почему не импортируются модули без расширения при использовании babel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babel

я не понимаю почему babel-node не импортирует без ".js" в import.

- Указан `"type": "module"` в package.js
- `import example from "./src/example.js";` работает
- `import example from "./src/example";` не работает
- `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node` работает когда я не использую babel-node

package.js

```
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node  ./index.js --exec babel-node -e js --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node "
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
        "express": "^4.18.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongoose": "^6.3.5",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
        "npm": "^8.12.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm install @babel/node` решил мою проблему. всё заработало.